# SQL Query using foreign key relationships

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-key-relationship

I am learning MySQL and I am trying to make simple arithmetic in the query,
I am trying to identify the department with the highest salary average and get the department name.
But I have no idea how to access to  `ProfessorsTable` table using the foreign key.
Can anyone help me in this? Thank you!

This is what I Tried:

```
 SELECT Department FROM ProfessorsTable WHERE max(AVG(Salary));
```

Here below are my two tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE DepartmentsTable
 (
   Department VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Faculty VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Building VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (Department)
 ) type = InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE ProfessorsTable
 (
   Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Department VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Rank VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Salary INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (Department) REFERENCES DepartmentsTable(Department), 
   CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (Name, Department)
 ) type = innoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the average salaries of all departments . . .

```
SELECT Department, avg(Salary) AS avg_salary
FROM ProfessorsTable 
GROUP BY Department
ORDER BY avg_salary DESC;
```

To get only the department with the highest average . . .

```
SELECT Department, avg(Salary) AS avg_salary
FROM ProfessorsTable 
GROUP BY Department
ORDER BY avg_salary DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you wish to do, the workflow would be as follows:

You want to select the Department name of the professor with the highest salary. Therefore, you want to sort the professors by salary, pick the first in the list (highest salary), and then return his/her department.

Try this:

```
SELECT Department FROM ProfessorsTable ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Edit:

I misread the original question. Here is the way to get the department name of the department with the highest salary:

```
SELECT Department FROM ProfessorsTable GROUP BY Department ORDER BY AVG(salary) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The basic idea is the sam though: you are first sorting by the average salary, then choosing to keep only the first result.

Comment: *"You want to select the Department name of the professor with the highest salary."*  That's not what the question asks for.